# Verify python PBKDF2 password hash in PHP

Tags: python, php, security, hash, odoo

I need to verify a PBKDF2 password hash stored in an external application (Odoo). I get the encrypted password by there API and just want to check if the entered password is correct.

I successfully verify the password using **Python**'s [passlib library](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html):

```
print pbkdf2_sha512.verify('test123', user['password_crypt'])
```

Now I need to implement that in PHP, I use the core [hash_pbkdf2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) function, but without success:

```
$expected = hash_pbkdf2('sha512', 'test123', 'Mua89x7jvLfWWqsVIoRwTg', 25000, 86);
echo $expected, PHP_EOL;
var_dump(hash_equals($expected, $user['password_crypt']));
```

The hash of the encrypted password (=$user['password_crypt']) as saved by Odoo is:

```
$pbkdf2-sha512$25000$Mua89x7jvLfWWqsVIoRwTg$znMkhiu7SAGVvLg4mWEDMQihxmSkOnzWUBTH.1jYaKGySzh9x4IDyExf0.R8Q0jA3XL6rgOys3jwnnYsvh92RQ
```

Am I right that the structure of the password is **$algo$iteration$salt$hash**? So it should show that number of *iterations* are 25000, *salt* is Mua89x7jvLfWWqsVIoRwTg and the hash *length* is 86.

But actually the output of variable $expected is different to saved hash:

```
69dd429a48dc5ac421126eb3561307f3f92113b6aa550bf35a3f3a91c20bfe28b7f9697d84bd59f1b49e22
```

So I could prepend the fixed part "$pbkdf2-sha512$25000$Mua89x7jvLfWWqsVIoRwTg$", but the hash part also is different. What am I doing wrong?

PS: Online example of discussed code at https://ideone.com/5c9w12

Comment: can you print  and report back the contents of `$expected`

Comment: Thanks! Output of $expected added.

Comment: Can you try doubling the lenght? E.G `hash_pbkdf2('sha512', 'test123', 'Mua89x7jvLfWWqsVIoRwTg', 25000, 172);`

Comment: scrap that, please base64 encode the  result, python implementation does that automatically, but the php implementation does not apparantly (after extensive digging)

Comment: should look like `$expected = base64_encode( hash_pbkdf2( "sha512", "test123", "Mua89x7jvLfWWqsVIoRwTg", 25000, 0, true ) );`

Comment: Just added a link to online code. So probably there is a problem with the length of the byte length, as it doesn't fit any more after base64 encoding...

Comment: i found some stackoverflow answers that might guide you further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391262/verifying-password-hashes-generated-by-python-passlib/33593013#33593013

Comment: Thanks for the link, the first provided answer works out perfectly. So actually base64 encoding is part of the solution, but there are some other hacks needed to get the right format for verifying the hash.

Comment: glad to help, figuring out wierd stuff like this is so much fun (when ur not on a deadline that is)